# Working directory for making pycaffe

Tags: python, compiler-errors, neural-network, ubuntu-14.04, caffe

I am trying to make caffe for python use using cmake. What I do is as follows:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make all
```

Then everything is built successfully.
But when I run the command for compiling python modules using `make pycaffe`, I get this error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `pycaffe'.  Stop.

Why is that? Which directory should be the working directory?

Comment: A more general answer that might still help would be what the argument to `make`, which in my case should be pycaffe, means

Comment: you should look at `Makefile` file to see a line that starts with `py$(PROJECT):`